# Download offline map at runtime in Flutter using Mapbox?

Tags: flutter, mapbox

We have a flutter application where we want to use map functionality in offline mode. 
Mapbox provides functionality in the flutter to use offline maps but .db file which contains offline data needs to be saved in the project at build time.

How to achieve the same at runtime?

also open to suggestions to use any other map service providers that works in both online and offline mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a file on the device please read the official Flutter documentation about [Reading and Writing Files](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)

Essentially you need to add `path_provider` package to your project in order to retrieve the standard cache folder for every device and then simply save you file in it.
This is a my application similar behaviour code

```dart
    //Get an available temporary dir on device using path_provider package
    final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

    //Create a path with file name
    final String tempPath = tempDir.path + '/' + 'yourFileName.db';
    //Write file on device disk
    final File file = File(tempPath);
    await writeAsBytesSync(fileContent); //If it is a string use writeAsStringAsync
    print('File written on disk');
```

Then using the file path you can simply read it from disk using `readAsByteAsync` method.

Remember that in the sample we are using `getTemporaryDirectory()` and as the documentation tell us

> Path to the temporary directory on the device that is not backed up and is suitable for storing caches of downloaded files.
>   Files in this directory may be cleared at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check out this issue on the github page of the flutter-mapbox-gl repository:

https://github.com/tobrun/flutter-mapbox-gl/issues/88

See the comment of vinceKruger:

https://github.com/tobrun/flutter-mapbox-gl/issues/88#issuecomment-559380534

It is not an official way, but seems to work!